# Function "pdist" in Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I have an N by 2 matrix called r (N is very large). r is the position of points in 2D. I searched for the best-optimized way of calculating distance between point. I find that dist function is the best on in less time-consuming if one doesn't try to change it to a square matrix. I wonder if I write

```
D= pdist(r, 'euclidean');
```

When I need distance between particle i and j, what is the best way to find it using D vector? I do not really any way without using if.
I know that I can do it by

```
if (i < j) 
    D((i–1)*(m–i/2)+j–i)
end
```

But as N is very large, this is not efficient. Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: Wherefore do you need it? Using an if test seems appropriate to me in general.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using  `ii` and `jj` as row and column indices into the hypohetical distance matrix `M = squareform(D)` of size and `N`. The result is `ind`,  such that `D(ind)` equals `M(ii,jj)`.

```
t = sort([ii, jj]); % temporary variable
ii = t(2); % maximum of ii and jj
jj = t(1); % minimum of ii and jj
t = N-1:-1:1;
ind = sum(t(1:jj-1)) + ii - jj;
```

Comment: is it faster than squareform(D)?

Comment: @SoniaSohi I thought you were more concerned about memory. As for speed, I don't know, better test yourself in your specific case